# Problem with rdlc Report in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, reportviewer

```
 private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeTo.Text).Date >= Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeFrom.Text).Date)
                {
                    DateTime today = DateTime.Today.Date;
                    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                    DataTable dtnew = new DataTable();
                    string EmpId = null;

                    if (ddlEmployee.SelectedIndex > 0)
                    {
                        EmpId = ddlEmployee.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    }

                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                    dtnew = new dbInOutTimeDatasetTableAdapters.InOutTableAdapter().GetData(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeTo.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeFrom.Text),new Guid(EmpId));
                    //   dtnew = new dsReportTableAdapters.ReportTableAdapter().GetData(Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeFrom.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimeTo.Text), EmpId, DeptId);

                    reportViewer1.Visible = true;
                    ReportDataSource rptds = new ReportDataSource("dbInOutTimeDataset_ReportInOut", dtnew);
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptds);
                    reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
                    reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
                    reportViewer1.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("To date must be greater or equal to From date.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException exI)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no any Employee Absent.", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unhandled Error:" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Problem: Cant bind the report in Reportviewer. I get the record in **"dtnew"**, but cnt see the report in my application

Get Error in report **" A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source 'dsInOutReport_InOut'"**

Comment: Could the problem be that you use another data source name in the report file ("dsInOutReport_InOut") than what you name in the code ("dbInOutTimeDataset_ReportInOut")?

Answer (score -1):

add this:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.clear();
```

before this:

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptds);
```

this will work.